# JavaScript (Processing.js) Number Not Changing

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing

**FIXED** Had a bounds error, needed to add <= to the nested for loops below

I'm making a "game" for school, and the way the map is organized is in a 3x3 2D array.

Whenever the player leaves the canvas, it changes the scene to a new one, unless they are on the edge of the area. The code for detecting them leaving the canvas is:

```
if(X <= 0){ 
if(curCol > 0){ 
             X = width;
             //Change current scene to FALSE before col is decremented
             scene[curRow][curCol] = false;
             sceneChanged = true;
             curCol--;
        }else{
                X = 0;
        }   
  }else if(Y <= 0){ 
        if(curRow > 0){ 
                scene[curRow][curCol] = false;
                sceneChanged = true;
                Y = height;
                curRow--;
        }else{
                Y = 0;
        }   
  }else if(Y >= height){
        if(curRow < 2){
             scene[curRow][curCol] = false;
                Y = 0 + radius;
                sceneChanged = true;
                curRow++;
        }else{
                Y = height;
        }
  }else if(X >= width){
        if(curCol < 2){
             scene[curRow][curCol] = false;
                X = 0 + radius;
                sceneChanged = true;
                curCol++;
        }else{
                X = width;
        }
  }
  //Set the new column and row to TRUE before sceneText()
  //That way the for loops at the start will find the correct new scene
  scene[curRow][curCol] = true;
if(sceneChanged){
  sceneText();
}
  sceneChanged = false;
```

**FIXED** The reason for the bug was a bounds error

And then the code which changes the background, text, etc. :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ <-- add <=
                for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++){ <-- add <=
                        if(scene[i][k]){
                                sceneNum = (k + 1) + (3 * i);
                        }
                }
        }
        console.log("row " + curRow);
        console.log("col " + curCol);
        console.log("scene " + sceneNum);
        switch(sceneNum){
                case 1:
                        zooText = "Welcome to the office. This is where we organize all our files. Important files include our certification by the AZA (Association of Zoos & Aquariums), and other"
                        + " important documents which certify we keep our animals healthy and happy";
                        r = 192;
                        g = 206;
                        b = 229;
                        break;
                case 2:
                        zooText = "This is the education area. Here we teach children about the importance of conservation, and protecting our planet. According to some people,"
             + "we're really influential!";
                        break;
                case 3:
                        console.log("scene 3");
                        zooText = "Scene 3";
                        break;
                case 4:
                        console.log("case 4");
                        r = 90;
                        g = 244;
                        b = 147;
                        zooText = "This is the Aquatic Area. Although most of these animals have natural roaming areas of hundreds of miles, we like to keep them in small enclosures";
                        break;
                case 5:

                        r = 132;
                        g = 112;
                        b = 255;
                        zooText = "Welcome to the zoo! You are going to explore what we do and how the animals live. WASD to move";
                        break;
                case 6:
                        console.log("scene 6");
                        zooText = "Here we have our conservation area. We house many endangered species which otherwise wouldn't survive in the wild. We breed them, so that " +
                                "we can eventually release them into the wild";
                        break;
                case 7:
                        console.log("scene 7");
                        zooText = "This is the research area. We conduct research on animals, mainly about their behavior. This research helps us protect them and other species"
   + "from harm in the future";
                        break;

  case 8:
                        console.log("scene 8");
                        zooText = "";
                        break;
                case 9:
                        console.log("scene 9");
                        zooText = "This is where we keep our animals over night. They are fed, given water, and are able to rest in the most comfortable arangments. The AZA makes sure we keep these"
 + "areas in tip-top shape, so that the animals don't suffer";
                        break;
                default:
                        break;

        }
```

The problem is that only the top left 4 parts of the array "update" the scene. So it would be setup like:

`__________________
|  1  |  4  |    |
|_____|_____|____|
| 2   |  5  |    |
|_____|_____|____|
|     |     |    |
|_____|_____|____|`

With the blank boxes, they will stay the same scene number as the last scene you were in.

So if you went from scene (box) 5 to the box to its right, instead of being scene 8, it will remain scene 5.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Sorry, edited to include issue

Comment: When you fix your own problem, you should either delete your question or post your own answer as a reply.